# Where do I go to turn OFF the Green Breakpoints in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I was messing around in Visual Studio 2015's *Tools > Options* menu a few weeks ago with a visiting developer.

I must have turned this feature ON, but now I want it back OFF.

[image]

Comment: What feature exactly?  That a breakpoint is hitting that line of code?  Or that the breakpoint highlight is green?  Or something else?

Comment: Before, my code would not break on these. They would just fall through to the exception handler. I wanted to know how to see the exceptions when they happened, but there are just too many of these in the code I am working on right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the menu `Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings` (accessible via Ctrl-Alt-E by default), you can toggle the debugger to break when specific exception types are hit.

[image: VS2015 Exception Settings Dialog]

Comment: That is exactly it. I had just found it and I was about to post the solution. Thanks, Harrision.